# Find QueryList<NgbDropdown> by id

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I need to find an element inside QueryList by id to be able to open it

```
<div ngbDropdown id="arquivo_1"></div>
<div ngbDropdown id="arquivo_2"></div>
<div ngbDropdown id="arquivo_3"></div>
...
<div ngbDropdown id="arquivo_9"></div>


<button type="button" (click)=open('arquivo_3')>Open 3</button>
```

ts

```
@ViewChildren(NgbDropdown) arquivos: QueryList<NgbDropdown>;


open(id: string): void {
  const element = document.getElementById(id);

  // find element ngbDropdown by id 
  this.arquivos.toArray()[3].open();
}
```

[image]

Comment: `this.arquivos.find(x => (x as any)._elementRef.nativeElement.id == 'arquivo_3').open();` looks weird but it works

Comment: Avoid manipulation private variables form lib @elvis-reis

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `dropdownClass` input property of NgbDropdown to bind the class to each dropdown parent.

```
<div ngbDropdown  dropdownClass="arquivo_1" id="arquivo_1"></div>
<div ngbDropdown  dropdownClass="arquivo_2" id="arquivo_2"></div>
<div ngbDropdown  dropdownClass="arquivo_3" id="arquivo_3"></div>
...
<div ngbDropdown  dropdownClass="arquivo_4" id="arquivo_9"></div>
```

Then in **component.ts** you can find respective dropdown using dropdownClass

```
open(id:string){
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    this.arquivos.toArray().find(({dropdownClass})=>dropdownClass === id).open();
  }
```

**[Working Sample Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ve1uz7?file=src/app/dropdown-basic.module.ts)**